# Unable to find PostGIS layer using PyQGIS in a standalone script

Tags: python, postgresql, postgis, qgis, pyqgis

I am working with a QGIS project (.qgs file) that references layers from a PostGIS database. I am trying to write a standalone Python script using PyQGIS that opens the project, finds a specific layer by name, and extracts its style to save it as an SLD file.

However, I am facing an issue where the find_layer_by_name function I have written is unable to find the layer, even though the layer exists in the project and loads correctly when I open the project in the QGIS desktop application.

Here is the Python function that I'm using to find the layer:

```
def find_layer_by_name(layer_name, group):
    # Check the layers in this group
    for layer in group.findLayers():
        if layer.name() == layer_name:
            return layer.layer()

    # Recursively check any sub-groups
    for sub_group in group.findGroups():
        found_layer = find_layer_by_name(layer_name, sub_group)
        if found_layer is not None:
            return found_layer

    # Layer was not found
    return None
```

An here's an attempt at using it:

```
from qgis.core import QgsApplication, QgsProject

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/path/to/qgis", True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()

project = QgsProject.instance()
project.read('project.qgs')

root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()

layer = find_layer_by_name("layer_name", root)
if layer is not None:
    print(f"Found layer: {layer.name()}")
else:
    print("Layer not found")

qgs.exitQgis()
```

When I run this script, it prints "Layer not found", even though the layer does exist in the project. If I uncomment the line `# print( layer.name() )` it does output layer names though.

I have confirmed that:

- The standalone script is running on the same machine where I'm able to load the project correctly in the QGIS desktop application.
- The standalone script and the QGIS desktop application are using the same version of QGIS.
- The standalone script is using the correct path to the QGIS installation.

I would appreciate any help in understanding why this script is unable to find the layer and how I can fix it. Thanks in advance!